# Django - When I extend index.html I don't get the variables

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I wrote an index.html and a views.py for it. I get the date and convert the month data as verbal as you see below. It works for index page, but when I extend the index page from other pages, date does not come.

```
def index(request):

    datenow = date.today()
    datemonth = date.today().month
    if datemonth == 8:
        date_month="Ağustos"
    elif datemonth == 9:
        date_month = "Eylül"
    elif datemonth == 10:
        date_month = "Ekim"
    elif datemonth == 11:
        date_month ="Kasım"
    elif datemonth == 12:
        date_month ="Aralık"
    elif datemonth == 1:
        date_month ="Ocak"
    elif datemonth == 2:
        date_month ="Şubat"
    elif datemonth == 3:
        date_month ="Mart"
    elif datemonth == 4:
        date_month ="Nisan"
    elif datemonth == 5:
        date_month ="Mayıs"
    elif datemonth == 6:
        date_month ="Haziran"
    elif datemonth == 7:
        date_month ="Temmuz"

    news = New.objects.all()[:10]
    programs= Program.objects.filter(date=date.today())
    print date.today()
    print date_month
    template = "index.html" 
    context = {'news':news,
               'programs':programs,
               'datenow':datenow,
               'date_month':date_month}
    return render_to_response(template,context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: What do you mean "when I exclude index page from other pages"?

Comment: i guess you mean ( extend) or (inherit ) and not ( exclude)

Comment: yes sorry I meant extend

Comment: Understand that there is NOT a direct link between the "index.html" you've created and the index() function you've created.  "index.html" is the template, and in itself does not call the index() function.  You must provide the variables to the template, via the 'context' dictionary, as done above, each time use the template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want this date and Time in Every pages, you should have to use Django context processors [Link Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors)

```
def datetime(request):

    datenow = date.today()
    datemonth = date.today().month
    if datemonth == 8:
        date_month="Ağustos"
    elif datemonth == 9:
    date_month = "Eylül"
    elif datemonth == 10:
        date_month = "Ekim"
    elif datemonth == 11:
    date_month ="Kasım"
    elif datemonth == 12:
        date_month ="Aralık"
    elif datemonth == 1:
        date_month ="Ocak"
    elif datemonth == 2:
        date_month ="Şubat"
    elif datemonth == 3:
        date_month ="Mart"
    elif datemonth == 4:
        date_month ="Nisan"
    elif datemonth == 5:
        date_month ="Mayıs"
    elif datemonth == 6:
        date_month ="Haziran"
    elif datemonth == 7:
        date_month ="Temmuz"


context = {'datenow':datenow,'date_month':date_month}
return context
```

in settings.py

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    'django.core.context_processors.csrf',
    # Custom Context Proccessors
    'apps.your-app.context_processor.datetime',


)
```

then in HTML files, you can use

`{{ datenow }}` and `{{ date_month }}`

Answer (score 0):

from what i understand. you have a page that extends from another one. but the other page does not show the inherited data.

that's simply because the `index.html` is being called from `views.py`. the variables and the updates are sent from the `view.index()`

when another page inherits `index.html` it does not update the date simply because it was handled by another function and not `views.index()` ( i hope my idea is clear here).

one simple solution to you problem is to copy the contents of the views.index and send the variables again to your new html template.

Comment: How can I do it for flatpages ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, then I think you are assuming extending the index.html page also extends the view  defined by `def index(request)`.  Unfortunately you will have to provide the date variable in each view as the the template `index.html` only provides a way to view the variables in an html format.

Rather than repeat your date formatting code in each view, this looks like a good case for a custom template filter. Have a look at converting your index function above into a templatetag (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) and then you could set the date in a view e.g.

```
def my_other_view(request):
    context = {'date': my_date }
```

and then in your template file you could build use `my_date_template_filter` like so

```
{extend 'index.html'}

{% block content %}
    {{ my_date|my_date_template_filter}}
{% endblock %}
```

Of course you would have to define a custom template filter as defined in the link above.